# merge column to the pyspark dataframe without impacting the rows

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 as shown below

df1:

```
+----------+------+
|CustomerNo|Amount|
+----------+------+
|   10024.0| 194.0|
|   10024.0| 194.0|
|  100342.0| 66.15|
|   10058.0| 199.0|
|   10080.0| 206.6|
|   10080.0| 206.6|
|   10080.0| 206.6|
|   10080.0| 206.6|
|   10080.0|   0.0|
|   10080.0|156.75|
```

df2:

```
+----------+---+
|CustomerNo|Qty|
+----------+---+
|   10024.0|  1|
|   10024.0|  1|
|  100342.0|  1|
|   10058.0|  1|
|   10080.0|  2|
|   10080.0|  3|
|   10080.0|  4|
|   10080.0|  5|
|   10080.0|  6|
|   10080.0|  7|
```

I want to join these two dataframe so that the new dataframe should have only CustomerNo, Qty and Amount with same rows

```
df = df1.join(df2, df1.CustomerNo==df2.CustomerNo,'inner')
```

While I am using the above code, the rows are increasing. I would like the final output to be in this format with just the column should be appended.

```
    |CustomerNo|Amount|Qty
    +----------+------+------+
    |   10024.0| 194.0|1
    |   10024.0| 194.0|1
    |  100342.0| 66.15|1
    |   10058.0| 199.0|1
    |   10080.0| 206.6|2
    |   10080.0| 206.6|3
    |   10080.0| 206.6|4
    |   10080.0| 206.6|5
    |   10080.0|   0.0|6
    |   10080.0|156.75|7
```

Comment: I don't think you can. As far as I know (not 100% sure, but...), there's no guarantee that you will get the same order next time. The same table may be split into smaller or larger number of nodes. So the order may depend on the order that you receive your records. Unless you have just one node, which you needed to specify in the question.

Comment: Do these rows match on both DataFrames? i.e. you have 5 occurrences of CustomerNo=1 on df1, then df2 will have 5 CustomerNo=1 too, but with different Qty?

Comment: yes, the rows match on both DataFrames @Kafels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this but.. you should be careful.  I'm going to show you how to use a window but they suck at performance so only use windows when you have to not as a first choice.  This should work but I'm guessing qty and amount are correlated.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

windowSpecQty  = Window.partitionBy("CustomerNo").orderBy("Qty")
windowSpecAmount  = Window.partitionBy("CustomerNo").orderBy("Amount")

rdf1 = df1.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpecAmount)) //grouped by CustomerNo given a rownumber

rdf2 = df2.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpecQty)) //grouped by CustomerNo given a rownumber

cond = [rdf1.CustomerNo==rdf2.CustomerNo, rdf1.row_number==rdf2.row_number]
df = rdf1.join(rdf2, cond,'inner').select( rdf1['CustomerNo'], rdf1['Amount'], rdf2['Qty'])
```